# SPLIT COLUMNS INTO BINARY MATRIX

Tags: mysql, split

Basically I have a column like this:

```
+----------------+
| Marks          |
+----------------+
|Maths,Phy,Che   |
|Maths,Phy       | 
|Phy,Che         |
|Che             |
|Maths,Phy,Che   |
|Maths,Phy,Che   |
+----------------+
```

And I would like to be like this

```
+-------------------------+-------+------+------+
| marks                   | Maths | Phy  | Che  |
+-------------------------+-------+------+------+
| Maths,Phy,Che           | 1     | 1    | 1   |
| Maths,Phy               | 1     | 1    | 0   |
| Phy,Che                 | 0     | 1    | 1   |
| Che                     | 0     | 0    | 1   |
| Maths,Phy,Che           | 1     | 1    | 1   |
| Maths,Phy,Che           | 1     | 1    | 1   |
+-------------------------+-------+------+------+
```

I was trying to use substring as posted in this answer ([how to split a column into multiple columns in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29093523/how-to-split-a-column-into-multiple-columns-in-mysql/49118293#49118293))

but I could not make it work the way I want

Comment: Your lone `Che` column has no way of knowing whether it should be `1, 0, 0` or `0, 0, 1`. You'll need some sort of map or array. You could also use `locate()` with multiple `case`s, as is demonstrated in the answer of the question you linked to.

Comment: Thanks I got that part, but I cannot get the '0' and '1'. I get '0' or nothing at all (where is should be a '1')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

could using column like value result

```
select marks
      , (marks like '%Maths%') as Maths
      , (marks like '%Phy%') as Phy
      , (marks like '%Che%') as Che
from my table
```

Comment: Thanks that works perfect, but what if I have more than 100 columns?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use MySQL `FIND_IN_SET` function. If that returns a 0 or NULL, the item was not found in the set. If it returns non-zero, that's the position of the item in the set. We can test the return from the function, and return just a zero or one.

Something like this:

```
  SELECT t.marks
       , IF(FIND_IN_SET( 'Maths'  ,t.marks),1,0) AS `Maths`
       , IF(FIND_IN_SET( 'Phy'    ,t.marks),1,0) AS `Phy`
       , IF(FIND_IN_SET( 'Che'    ,t.marks),1,0) AS `Che`
    FROM column_like_this t
```